# Easiest way to see that $\log X < X^a$ as $X \to \infty$ for fixed $a > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a > 0$. It is "obvious" that for large enough $X$, we have $X^a > \log X$. I would like to prove this using as little machinery as possible. Here are two approaches:

1. One way to do this is to note that our goal is equivalent to $X < \exp\{X^a\}$ as $X\to\infty$. The Taylor series of $\exp$ at $0$ will have terms of order greater than $X$, so we can see the aymptotic from that.
2. We could also observe that
   $$
   X^a - \log X = 1 + \int_1^X t^{-1}(t^a - 1)dt.
   $$
   Let $C$ be a real number such that $C^a \geq 2$. For $X \geq C$, we have
   $$
   \int_C^X t^{-1}(t^a - 1) dt \geq \int_C^X t^{-1} = \log X - \log C,
   $$
   and it follows that
   $$
   X^a - \log X = k + \log X 
   $$
   for some constant $k$. Since $\log X \to \infty$ as $X\to \infty$, it follows that $X^a > \log X$ for large enough $X$.

These arguments both feel a bit unsatisfying to me. The first one uses Taylor series, which feel like quite heavy machinery, and the second one, while more elementary, feels like it doesn't really get to the heart of *why* $X^a$ is bigger than $\log X$. Can anyone see a more satisfying argument? I would also accept an answer that convinces me that one of my two arguments is actually a nice solution; currently I don't have much intuition for the aesthetics of these sorts of proofs.

Answer (score 2):

**A Simple Inequality**

For $x\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(x)
&=\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}t\tag{1a}\\
&\le x-1\tag{1b}\\[6pt]
&\le x\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ definition
$\text{(1b):}$ $t\ge1$ over the domain of integration
$\text{(1c):}$ $x-1\le x$

---

**The Desired Inequality**

Substituting $x\mapsto x^{a/2}$ into $(1)$ and multiplying by $\frac2a$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log(x)
&\le\frac2ax^{a/2}\tag{2a}\\
&=\left(\frac2ax^{-a/2}\right)x^a\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
For $x\ge\left(\frac2a\right)^{2/a}$, we have $\frac2ax^{-a/2}\le1$, and thus,
$$
\log(x)\le x^a\tag3
$$

Comment: $x\ge\left(\frac{\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-a)}{-a}\right)^{1/a}$ is the minimum lower bound for a given $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly clean proof which only relies on L'Hopital's. Let $a > 0$, then we want to compute:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^a}{\log(x)}
$$
We observe that in the limit, both the numerator and denominator go to infinity, so we can use L'Hopital's to get:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^a}{\log(x)}
 = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ax^{a-1}}{\frac{1}{x}} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} a x^a = \infty
$$

So we see that if we fix $C>0$, for sufficiently large $N$, anytime $x > N$, we have:
$$
\frac{x^a}{\log(x)} > 1 \implies x^a > C\log(x)
$$
Specializing to $C = 1$, we get the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We can analyze the sign of $f(x) = x^a - \log x$ as $x > 0$ by instead considering the composition
$$f(e^u) = (e^u)^a-\log(e^u) = e^{au} - u$$

This is similar to your first method, but with the benefit that $e^{au}$ is easier to analyze than $e^{x^a}$.

Specifically, *if we already know* $e^y \geq \frac12y^2$ for every $y>0$, then we're able to write, for any $u>0$,
$$f(e^u) \geq \frac12a^2u^2 - u = \frac{a^2u}2\left(u-\frac2{a^2}\right),$$
showing $f(e^u) > 0$ when $u > 2/a^2$.

Letting $x > e^{2/a^2}$ then shows $\log x > 2/a^2$ and $$f(x) = f(e^{\log x}) > 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way
using only the definition of $\ln$
as an integral.

For $x > 0, c>0$

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&\lt\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{(1+t)^{1-c}}\\
&=\int_0^{x} (1+t)^{c-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{(1+t)^c}{c}|_0^{x}\\
&=\dfrac{(1+x)^c-1}{c}\\
&\lt\dfrac{(1+x)^c}{c}\\
&\text{so, replacing }c \text{ by } c/2\\
\ln(1+x)
&\lt\dfrac{(1+x)^{c/2}}{c/2}\\
&\text{or}\\
\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x^c}
&\lt\dfrac{2}{c(1+x)^{c/2}}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } x \to \infty\\
\text{so that}\\
\dfrac{(\ln(1+x))^k}{x^{ck}}
&\lt\dfrac{2^k}{c^k(1+x)^{ck/2}}\\
&\text{Replacing } c \text{ by } c/k\\
\dfrac{(\ln(1+x))^k}{x^{c}}
&\lt\dfrac{2^k}{(c/k)^k(1+x)^{c/2}}\\
&=\dfrac{(2k/c)^k}{(1+x)^{c/2}}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } x \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 < b < \min \{1, a\}$, and let $c = \max\left\{\frac1b, \frac{\log b}{b-a}\right\} \ge 0$ then for $u\ge c$,

\begin{align}
\log u &= \log \frac1b + \int_{\frac1b}^u \frac{\mathrm d t}t\\
&\le - \log b + b\int_{\frac1b}^u \mathrm d t\\
&\le -\log b + b\left(u-\frac1b\right)\\
&\le -\log b + bu\\
&\le -\log b + (b-a)u + au\\
&\le au
\end{align}

Now for $x \ge e^c$, we have $\log x \ge c$ and so,

$$\log \log x \le a \log x\quad \implies \quad \log x \le x^a$$

Answer (score 0):

A proof using only the fact that $\ln'(x) = 1/x$ (and $\ln(x^a) = a \ln(x)$, wich is a corollary of the first fact). The idea of the proof is that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is very small compared to  the derivative of the power function $x^a$ for big $x$. Thus, the function $x^a$ is very big compared to $\ln(x)$ for big $x$.

Taking $y = x^a$ the problem is equivalent to prove that, for $y$ big enough : $$y > a \ln(y)$$
Consider the function $f(y) = y - a \ln(y)$. The derivative of $f$ is $f'(y) = 1 - \frac{a}{y}$. For $y > a^{-1}$, then $f'(y) > 0$ Consequently: $$\forall y > a^{-1},~f(y) > f(a^{-1}) = a^{-1} + a \ln(a)$$

Define $g(a) = a^{-1} + a \ln(a)$. Then $g'(a) = -a^{-2} + \ln(a)+1$ and $g''(a) = 2a^{-3} + a^{-1} > 0$.

1. If $a > 1$, then $g'(a) > g'(1) = 0$. Thus, $g(a) > g(1) = 1$.
2. If $a \leq 1$, then $g'(a) \leq g'(1) = 0$. Thus, $g(a) \geq g(1) = 1$.

We have obtained, that :
$$\forall y > a^{-1},~ y - a \ln(y) \geq 1 > 0$$
Or, with $x$ :
$$\forall x > a^{-a}, ~x^a > \ln(x)$$